# How can I Use Group Policy to send a Message to specific OU?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server, windows-server-2019

Setup is simple: windows server 2022

The issue is we need to reach some people when they login (but not the entire company) I can put those users into a security group, but what I need to happen is to have the server send them a message when they login and then say every so often afterwards while they are working.

The idea is to reach out to owners of certain company devices to let them know that we need to see their device for whatever reasons (Compliance, security, routine maint, etc)

For most of our users, this is an email/text message, for others it's a phone call, but there are a select few that we need a more 'aggressive' campaign for. (Company policy is that we can not simply lock their devices or accounts, so that's not an option.)

My idea was as simple as having the server send them the message every so often.

I tried using Scheduled Tasks to do this, which according to my research should work. In fact "Schedule a task (at least windows 7)" actually has  message send option. The problem is that the message never sends.

I have it applied to the correct OUs (In this case Authenticated Users & the Security Group) but it doesn't seem to want to execute to the people in the group.

Any ideas or suggestions, or alternate routes?

Comment: Sounds like a "Contact HR / Management" issue, IMHO

Comment: @squillman ... Yeah, thing is we're short staffed severely, so they know they can be sh!^Z about it and management is pretty held up. That's exactly the issue, that's why our ED will not let us just block their accounts, they need the employees to work. So my idea is to make it just annoying enough that they want to call us over in IT.

Comment: Sending a message is blocked by default, but I think you can somehow enable it. Maybe GPO, dunno. Has been a long time since I looked into it.

Comment: Also, I honestly think you should not automate this, but rather go social in this. Contact them directly and if that does not lead to anything, contact their superior.

Comment: Send an email? Lock down their device until they show up for service? I know desktop notices are possible. My org uses them. Reminders to complete an employee survey. But I'm not on the team that does that.